# How to fetch and display the images from AWS S3 bucket in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

I am new to angular 7 and I need to fetch and display the images from AWS S3 bucket using AWS Cognito (i have identity pool id along with me).

I have installed AWS SDK, S3, AWS Cognito in my project and tried to fetch and display the images but am getting only the image URL which I have no access so please guide me on this

```
viewAlbum(albumName:any) {
  var albumBucketName = 'XXXX';
  var bucketRegion = 'XXXX';
  var IdentityPoolId = 'XXXXX';
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  AWS.config.update({
    region: bucketRegion,
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
      })
  });
  var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    params: {Bucket: albumBucketName}
  });
  var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName);
  s3.listObjects({Prefix: albumPhotosKey}, function(err:any, data:any) {
    console.log("photos::::",data)
    if (err) {
      return alert('There was an error viewing your album: ' + err.message);
    }
    var href = this.request.httpRequest.endpoint.href;
    var bucketUrl = href + albumBucketName + '/';

    var photos = data.Contents.map(function(photo:any) {
    var photoKey = photo.Key;
    var photoUrl = bucketUrl + encodeURIComponent(photoKey);
    console.log("viewalbus::::",photoUrl)
    });
  });
}
```

**Expected output:**

I should able to display the images

**Actual result:**

I can't able to fetch the images URL or display it

Comment: Few things: How do you use this together with Angular specifically? Do you get any errors - does this `console.log` show the proper url?

Comment: yaaa Zlatko
i am getting the image url
but i need to get the pre signed URL

Comment: Can you show the actual angular code? You know you have to sanitize the url with Angulars `DomSanitizer`?

Comment: Hi zlatko,
This is the code which am having but there is no errors in it while compiling 
please help me how to use angulars DomSanitizer

Comment: Well I would, but first you need to show how are you using the function you're showing in your Angular code? Have you got Angular code?

Comment: i am using the above code only in component.ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acualy you need to get signed URL from S3 :

Make sure the sdk is installed and configure it (user_id , secret_key) :

```
npm install aws-sdk
```

Then

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';


let s3= new AWS.S3();

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Key: myKey
})

console.log(url)
```

Comment: Hi abderrahim,
thanks for your reply

actually i have only three data
bucketregion ,
bucket name,
identity pool id
and not key

so i cant use the above code
is there any way to get the presigned url by using cognito

Comment: The key is the name of the file on the bucket S3

Comment: Cognito is another service (manage identity and users) You need just to use S3 using the method `getSignedUrl()` to get your url but you need to have bucket name and filename.

Comment: but am getting error like
ERROR ReferenceError: global is not defined